# Procedural terrain Parenting script

Tags: python, game-engine

I wrote a script with 3 while loops for a 10x10x10 xyz range and creates block of terrain at each XYZ made of voxels, cutting off each column of voxels at a noise value which gives a terrain look.

I am trying to parent the voxels to an empty so they can start working in chunks and be deleted in groups, but when I use an empty to place them and parent them to the spawner empty (another empty), the entire terrain flips upside down, not the individual cubes, but the terrain cut off looks flat on the top but on the bottom of the 10x10x10 block is the hills upside down.

How do i fix it to have the terrain work again?

Comment: The primary culprit code is narrowed down to two lines of code which is a scene.addObject line where I use the other empty (not the spawner empty with the code on it) to place the blocks, and a parent line of code to parent cubes to the spawner empty.  The two are dependent of each other due to the fact the placer empty is used in the scene.addobject line.  And to work it needs to be parented to the original spawner empty or something.  If it would help I can draw a diagram of what is going on or give code which could simplify any confusion.

Comment: I have a visual reprentation of my problem on a Google+ post.  Here is a link : https://plus.google.com/115731765934668406440/posts/F1EJA38RdHE

Comment: Good news!  I have fixed the problem by changing which empty is the parent.